# Setting the spacing between ToolBars within a ToolBarTray

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, toolbar

I have a `ToolBarTray` with multiple `ToolBar` inside. My objective is to have all these toolbars separated with a vertical line.
[image: The ToolBarTray I want]

Currently, I have sub-classed `ToolBar` class and programmatically made the toolbar's border non-rounded (default borders have rounded corners). However, there is this spacing between the toolbars that I am unable to get rid of.
[image: How the ToolBarTray looks like now]

I can probably remove ToolBarTray totally, and instead use Grid or StackPanel to achieve this. However, I need to retain the ability for the toolbars to be draggable/re-arrangeable.

Is there any simple solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this toolbar style

```
<Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToolBarHorizontalBackground" Color="#FFEEF5FD"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToolBarToggleButtonVerticalBackground" Color="#FFEEF5FD"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToolBarButtonHover" Color="#210080FF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToolBarGripper" Color="#FF6D6D6D"/>
        <Style x:Key="ToolBarVerticalOverflowButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarToggleButtonVerticalBackground}"/>
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0,0,3,3" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="6" Margin="2,7,2,2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="7">
                                <Path Data="M 1.5 1 L 1.5 6" Stroke="White"/>
                                <Path Data="M 0.5 0 L 0.5 5" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                                <Path Data="M 3.5 0.5 L 7 3.5 L 4 6.5 Z" Fill="White"/>
                                <Path Data="M 3 -0.5 L 6 2.5 L 3 5.5 Z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonHover}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonHover}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarGripper}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.HighContrast}}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToolBarVerticalBackground" Color="#FFEEF5FD"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToolBarToggleButtonHorizontalBackground" Color="#FFEEF5FD"/>
        <Style x:Key="ToolBarHorizontalOverflowButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarToggleButtonHorizontalBackground}"/>
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0,3,3,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="7" Margin="7,2,2,2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="6">
                                <Path Data="M 1 1.5 L 6 1.5" Stroke="White"/>
                                <Path Data="M 0 0.5 L 5 0.5" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                                <Path Data="M 0.5 4 L 6.5 4 L 3.5 7 Z" Fill="White"/>
                                <Path Data="M -0.5 3 L 5.5 3 L 2.5 6 Z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonHover}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonHover}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarGripper}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.HighContrast}}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToolBarMenuBorder" Color="#FFB6BDC5"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToolBarSubMenuBackground" Color="#FFEEF5FD"/>
        <Style x:Key="ToolBarThumbStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                        <Border Background="Transparent" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <Rectangle>
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewbox="0,0,4,4" Viewport="0,0,4,4" ViewportUnits="Absolute" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
                                        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                            <DrawingGroup>
                                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="White" Geometry="M 1 1 L 1 3 L 3 3 L 3 1 z"/>
                                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="{StaticResource ToolBarGripper}" Geometry="M 0 0 L 0 2 L 2 2 L 2 0 z"/>
                                            </DrawingGroup>
                                        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                    </DrawingBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeAll"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ToolBarMainPanelBorderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,11,0"/>
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="3,3,3,3"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.HighContrast}}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ToolBarStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ToolBar}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarHorizontalBackground}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolBar}">
                        <Grid x:Name="Grid" Margin="3,1,-3,1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <!--<Grid x:Name="OverflowGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                <ToggleButton x:Name="OverflowButton" ClickMode="Press" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" IsChecked="{Binding IsOverflowOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding HasOverflowItems}" Style="{StaticResource ToolBarHorizontalOverflowButtonStyle}"/>
                                <Popup x:Name="OverflowPopup" AllowsTransparency="true" Focusable="false" IsOpen="{Binding IsOverflowOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom" StaysOpen="false">
                                    <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent">
                                        <Border x:Name="ToolBarSubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ToolBarMenuBorder}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{StaticResource ToolBarSubMenuBackground}" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                            <ToolBarOverflowPanel x:Name="PART_ToolBarOverflowPanel" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" Focusable="true" Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle" WrapWidth="200"/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                                </Popup>
                            </Grid>-->
                            <Border x:Name="MainPanelBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" >
                                <DockPanel KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                                    <Thumb x:Name="ToolBarThumb" Margin="-3,-1,0,0" Padding="6,5,1,6" Style="{StaticResource ToolBarThumbStyle}" Width="10"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ToolBarHeader" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0,4,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <ToolBarPanel x:Name="PART_ToolBarPanel" IsItemsHost="true" Margin="0,1,2,2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsOverflowOpen" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" TargetName="ToolBarThumb" Value="false"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="Header" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ToolBarHeader" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ToolBarTray.IsLocked" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ToolBarThumb" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <!--<Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="OverflowPopup" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                                <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" TargetName="Shdw" Value="true"/>
                                <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000"/>
                            </Trigger>-->
                            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Grid" Value="1,3,1,1"/>
                                <!--<Setter Property="Style" TargetName="OverflowButton" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarVerticalOverflowButtonStyle}"/>-->
                                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="ToolBarThumb" Value="10"/>
                                <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ToolBarThumb" Value="Auto"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="ToolBarThumb" Value="-1,-3,0,0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Padding" TargetName="ToolBarThumb" Value="5,6,6,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="ToolBarHeader" Value="0,0,0,4"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="PART_ToolBarPanel" Value="1,0,2,2"/>
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ToolBarThumb" Value="Top"/>
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ToolBarHeader" Value="Top"/>

                                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="MainPanelBorder" Value="0,0,0,11"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarVerticalBackground}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.HighContrast}}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

then try toolbar style

```
<Grid>
        <ToolBarTray x:Name="ToolTray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"   Background="SkyBlue">
            <ToolBar Band="0" BandIndex="0" Style="{DynamicResource ToolBarStyle1}">
                <Button Background="Aqua" Height="25" Width="25" Content="0" />
                <Button Background="BlueViolet" Height="25" Width="25" Content="0" />
                <Button Background="CornflowerBlue" Height="25" Width="25" Content="0"/>
            </ToolBar>
            <ToolBar Band="0" BandIndex="1" Style="{DynamicResource ToolBarStyle1}">
                <Button Background="Aqua" Height="25" Width="25" Content="1"/>
                <Button Background="BlueViolet"  Height="25" Width="25" Content="1"/>
                <Button Background="CornflowerBlue" Height="25" Width="25" Content="1"/>
            </ToolBar>

        </ToolBarTray>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: It worked. I supposed this is converted back to resource from template. Can I ask where is the crucial part that changed this bahavior?

Comment: I found the crucial part and suggested another way to do the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

Based on Joby's answer, I have came up with an alternative. Hopefully, this can help someone else some time down the road later. Both methods basically do the same thing, but they are implemented differently. Depending on different situations, it may be more appropriate to use a specific one of the two.

The critical part of original answer is to change the `Grid` element in the `Template`, such that the right margin is `-3` (to offset the left margin of `3`).

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolBar}">
            <Grid x:Name="Grid" Margin="3,1,-3,1" ...
...
```

The alternative way to do this thing without re-defining the whole template, is to subclass `ToolBar` class:

```
class MyToolBar : ToolBar
{
    public NoOverflowToolBar()
        : base()
    {
        this.Loaded += MyToolBar_Loaded;
    }

    void MyToolBar_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToolBar toolBar = sender as ToolBar;
        var grid = toolBar.Template.FindName("Grid", toolBar) as FrameworkElement;
        if (grid != null)
        {
            grid.Margin = new Thickness(3, 1, -3, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

### Update

After having some experience in writing custom controls, I realized that there is no need to write this using `Loaded` event - just use `OnApplyTemplate()` override.

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    var grid = this.Template.FindName("Grid", this) as FrameworkElement;
    if (grid != null)
    {
        grid.Margin = new Thickness(3, 1, -3, 1);
    }
}
```